# mongodb ISODate problems

Tags: java, mongodb, isodate

I am using java(IDE is eclipse) to query on mongodb. Below is my java code:

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
ObjectId id =new ObjectId("529f280b90ee58cb7732c2b8");
query.put("_id", id);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    DBObject object = (DBObject)(cursor.next());
    System.out.println(object.get("_id"));
    System.out.println(object.get("createDate"));
}
```

Problems happened in the createDate whose type is ISODate and value is `ISODate("2013-10-21T01:34:04.808Z")`, but the `println` result of my code  is `'Mon Oct 21 **09**:34:04 CST 2013'`, **the hour has changed from 01 to 09**. I don't know what happened!

Can anybody help?

Comment: Look at the timezones - one is Zulu time (i.e. UTC), the one you print out is `CST`.

Comment: Yes.You mean all the ISODate value in mongodb use UTC time zone?Does this mean that before I insert a DateTime whose time zone is not UTC,I have to translate it manually into UTC and then insert it to mongodb?

Comment: It shouldn't need to be "manual", but yes, it's [a good practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices) to store dates as UTC, converting them as and when necessary for the end user.

Comment: A java.util.Date object has no time zone information, yet when printed by implicitly calling its `toString()` method, it confusingly renders using the JVM's default time zone. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20943600/642706).

Answer (score 2):

The hour did not change. You must be in China, given the "CST" in your example and the 8 hour difference. If you interpret "CST" as "[China Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/asia/cst.html)" (rather than [Central Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/cst.html) in the US), then you have a time zone that is 8 hours ahead of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT. So when ti is 1 AM UTC/GMT, at the vary same moment the clock on the wall in Taipei will read "9 AM".

Minor point: Those three-letter codes for time zones are obsolete and should be avoided. They are neither standardized nor unique. Use [proper time zone names](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html).

Major point: The problem lies in how you extract a value from MongoDB that represents a date-time.

I don't know MongoDB, and [their doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/) is confusing, so I can't help you much further. If you can retrieve an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string as seen in your first example, that is much preferable to the format of your second example.

If you want to work with the date-time value in Java, you can feed an ISO 8601 string directly to a [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) constructor in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2013-10-21T01:34:04.808Z" );
```

---

### Update

[This doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-types/#JavaTypes-Dates/Times) says that the Java driver for MongoDB will give you a java.util.Date object. That explains your problem. The java.util.Date & Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously bad. One problem is that while a Date instance has no time zone, its `toString()` method uses the JVM's default time zone to render a string. And Date's toString method uses that terrible ambiguous format.

You should avoid using java.util.Date & Calendar classes. For now use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. In Java 8, you can use the new [java.time.* classes](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

You can convert back and forth between java.util.Date and Joda-Time. Pass a Date instance to Joda-Time constructor. To go back, call Joda-Time `toDate()` format.

Note that while a java.util.Date has no time zone information within it, in contrast a DateTime object does have a time zone assigned. If you want UTC/GMT, specify `DateTimeZone.UTC`.

Your code should look more like:

```java
java.util.Date date = object.get("createDate");
DateTime createDateTime = new DateTime( date, DateTimeZone.forId( "Asia/Manila" ) );
System.out.println( createDateTime );
… do some work …
java.util.Date dateGoingBackToMongoDB = createDateTime.toDate();
```